# Receiving response from PHP via AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to send information from a form on my website to a `PHP` script using `Ajax`. However each time I try to submit the form I get no response back from the script on the server. I don't know what I'm missing and I'd appreciate any help.

This is my `HTML`:

```
<form method='post' action='<?= get_template_directory_uri() ?>/mailchimp.php'>
    <input type='text' name='email'/>
    <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Subscribe'/>
</form>
```

This is my `PHP`:

```
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    if(!empty($email) && !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false){
        // MailChimp API credentials
        $apiKey = 'xxx-xxx';
        $listID = 'xxxxxxx';

        // MailChimp API URL
        $memberID = md5(strtolower($email));
        $dataCenter = substr($apiKey,strpos($apiKey,'-')+1);
        $url = 'https://' . $dataCenter . '.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/' . $listID . '/members/' . $memberID;

        // member information
        $json = json_encode([
            'email_address' => $email,
            'status'        => 'subscribed'
        ]);

        // send a HTTP POST request with curl
        $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'user:' . $apiKey);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: application/json']);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        curl_close($ch);

        echo "<h1>Success</h1>";
    }
}
```

This is my `JQuery`:

```
jQuery('form').submit(function (event) {

   console.log('submitting...')

    //1. Get the form Data
    var formData = {
        'email': jQuery('input[name=email]').val()
    }

    console.log("DATA FROM FORM:")
    console.log(formData);

    //2. Process the form
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST', //Type of HTTP request
        url: 'mailchimp.php', //URL to POST
        data: formData //Data from form
    }).done(function (data) {
        console.log("RESPONSE: " + data);
    });

    //3. Stop the form from submitting in usual manner
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

I've checked my console and I can see no errors from the `JS`. I see this:

```
submitting...
DATA FROM FORM:
Object {email: "xyz@domain.com"}
RESPONSE:
```

I've also checked my network requests and I can see that I've requested the `PHP` script and it's sent a 200 reponse back so I am hitting the script - however I am not seeing any Response data.

*Also please note - I know in my above PHP code I don't check the `$httpCode` variable. I will be implementing this. I just want to get the scripts talking to eachother first.

Comment: Is display_errors on and error_reporting set to E_ALL in your php?

Comment: if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ is the problem remove this.

Comment: @Orlangure - Yes I just added it there, but no change

Comment: i think u dont have `$_POST['submit']`

Comment: this is good to see that, u r debuggin your code in JS, u also need to debug code in php.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That happen because your condition :

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
```

Will never reach since you don't sent the `submit` parameter in your `POST` request you send just the `email`.

So remove the condition or replace it by `isset($_POST['email'])`, or also you could add the `submit` parameter to your `formData`.

> To make sure that the request sent to the right route try to comment all the code and add an echo (e.g `echo "<h1>Test</h1>";`) and check if it will be logged.

Hope this helps.

Comment: downvote without comments hurt me also :( vote for u :)

Comment: This is incorrect, he has named the submit input, therefore it'll be passed.

Comment: @HenrikAronsson: OP using AJAX here

Comment: @HenrikAronsson: i appreciate your comment you are brave person who DV and comment also, good work bro.. :)

Comment: Thanks @devpro for your intervention.. Henrik no worries that happen.

Comment: i have added my answer also with CURL related suggestion,, this will also help to OP. @HenrikAronsson

Answer (score 2):

As i mentioned and others saying you are not using index `submit` in your ajax request which means you have undefined index warning in your PHP code.

This is better to use php `error_reporting()` in your PHP code, this will help to find out errors and warnings.

```
// Same as error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);

// Report all PHP errors (see changelog)
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Second, if you still want to add check in your code than you can use:

```
if(count($_POST) > 0)
```

or

```
if(isset($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['email']))
```

In last, you want this response from CURL request? `echo "<h1>Success</h1>";`
It means you always get the success message **either curl execute or not**.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your php script :

```
if(isset($_POST['email'])){

}
```

not bellow

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

}
```